# Using maven to copy war via ssh

Tags: maven, wagon

I want to copy war file via ssh. I have the following pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-cli</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>upload-single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</fromFile>
          <toFile>ROOT.war</toFile>
          <url>scpexe://my.server.com</url>
          <serverId>my.server.id</serverId>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I trying to execute mvn wagon:upload-single, I got the following message:

```
Embedded error: Error executing command for transfer
Exit code 255 - Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

My settings.xml have proper username and password set. Also i can copy file to remote host manually without any propblem via scp.

Please, help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I change

```
<toFile>ROOT.war</toFile>
<url>scpexe://my.server.com</url>
```

to

```
<toFile>/tmp/ROOT.war</toFile>
<url>scp://my.server.com</url>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! In my case console tells me: "Embedded error: Cannot connect. Reason: Auth fail". Maybe you don't have to input password for "/tmp"?..

Comment: "Embedded error: Cannot connect. Reason: Auth fail" - I got this error message when the password in the `settings.xml` is wrong. Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, password is correct. I use the same password for manual command execution (using ctrl+c/ctrl+v). I think the problem is in ssh. I read somewhere that I have to generate ssh key and add one to the reciever server. Anyway, thank you ) If i solve the problem, I will write there.

Answer (score 0):

You copy your file to the root folder. If you use this:

```
<toFile>ROOT.war</toFile>
<url>scpexe://my.server.com</url>
```

Then it is like saying: copy to my.server.com, us this file path: /ROOT.war

It is unlikely you have access to that folder.

Try using for example your home folder:

```
<toFile>/home/username/ROOT.war</toFile>
<url>scpexe://my.server.com</url>
```